# LightSwitch build fails using SQL Server 2014 LocalDB and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, localdb, sql-server-2014

I have **SQL Server 2014** installed and want to use `localdb\v12.0` in Visual Studio. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer) post and understand how to connect to localdb using SQL Server Object Explorer successfully. Now I have created a **LightSwitch** project in Visual Studio 2013 and when building it throws exception:

> An error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>   instance '(LocalDB)\v11.0'.

Seems it is looking for SQL Server 2012 to create the development database in Bin\Data and I don't have SQL Server 2012 so there is no `localdb\v11.0` on the system. So

1. Why does VS 2013 try to use `localdb\v11.0`?
2. How can I force Visual Studio to use `localdb\v12.0` when building the project?

I tried changing the _IntrinsicData connection string in `web.config` but when building again it throws the same exception trying to use `localdb\v11.0` which belongs to SQL Server 2012!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok after spending lots of time I found what was the problem! Here is the cause and solution:

LightSwitch uses SQL Express [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) to store information such as User and Roles when building the project (this is called development database). There is no problem with SQL Server 2012 but if SQL Server 2014 is installed something force the LightSwitch to connect to (localdb)\v11.0 . LightSwitch makes three projects in the solution. If the Client and the Server projects build successfully so the problem is with the third project. Go through these steps:

1. Right-Click on the third project in the solution
2. Select `Unload Project`
3. Again Right-Click on it and select `Edit <yourProjectName>.lsxtproj`
4. Search the **SqlExpressInstancename**
5. You will find its value is (localDB)\v11.0 !
6. Change it to the right SQL Server LocalDB instance name; for more information check the notes below

[image]

Now the solution successfully build

--

**Note 1:** To see which version of SQL Server LocalDb is installed, open cmd and type *sqllocaldb.exe v*

**Note 2:** To which instance of LocalDb has been created on the system, open cmd and type *sqllocaldb.exe info*

**Note 3:** The instance which is going to be used by LightSwitch must be started: open cmd and type *sqllocaldb.exe start*

---

**UPDATE:** Looking for a better solution I found the correct way to fix this problem. It was a pain for me to follow those 6 steps every time I create a new LightSwitch project. So if you want to fix it once you can do it this way:

1. In Visual Studio go to Tools->Options
2. In the Database Tools select the Data Connections
3. Set your desired SQL Server Instance Name

[image]

So no need to set it every time you create a LS project

Comment: Possible database\instance names with VS2015 and LocalDB version 12 are **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB** and **(localdb)\ProjectsV12**.