# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I get that error when I try to debug my program. Searched for this error but could not really figure it out on my own. Also when I try to connect my database I get this error "`error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`".

```
public DataTable ReadData(string st_proc, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = st_proc;
    command.Connection = conn;
    if (param != null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    }
    SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    db.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What is your connection string looks like?

Comment: What is the connection here (-minus the actual ip and password) ? Is the server on separate network? Does it need vpn?

Comment: `Data Source=(Localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=E:\Hotel\App_Hotel\DB_Hotel;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True\DB_Hotel.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True` I did not make it. @SonerGönül

Comment: @ArghyaC Its server, it does not need vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have got the connection string from some else's machine. Here `Data Source=(Localdb)\mssqllocaldb;` means it is pointing to `"[Sql Server Express LocalDB 2014][1]"`.
Make sure you have it installed on you machine. You can also try [connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer) to `DataSource=(Localdb)\v11.0;` which is "Sql server express 2012" and use it in your connection string. See if this works.