# Couldn't add Database file in Visual Studio 2013 . Error 50

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Yes I know that this question has been asked many times, but this problem seems to be persistent.

I have had this error before but that was during hosting on IIS.For that reason I shifted from **VS2013** to **VS2010**. There is no problem in VS2010, but I need VS2013 and now here I stand where I can't even add a **DATABASE FILE**.

Now here is the error which I am getting while adding a database :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 – Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details. )

Now I understand there is some error with the MS SQL's version, I tried all that is said within this : **http://kbijayanta.azurewebsites.net/tag/localdbv12-0/** link.

Here is a look at my Control Panel and the SQL related programs I have :

[image]

What is a definitive solution for this ?

**P.S. :**  I have not installed any packages/programs/applications relating SQL server. All this was pre installed with my VS 2013 installation!

**UPDATE**

Here is the screen capture of the errors in the Event Log : 
[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer to see if there is any additional information there, per the error message?

Comment: Please look at my updated question ! and Please tell me what to look into Event Viewer ?

Comment: What you posted is not the event viewer.  Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer and then look in the Windows Logs -> Application to see if there are any errors logged there.

Comment: Without seeing the event log or the connection string, hard to guess - but maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis.aspx)? .... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26267373/822637)?

Comment: @Tim : I ll add the Event Log in a moment

Comment: @Tim : Please look at the screen capture I added

Comment: @sq33G : simply doing `localdb create "v12.0"` doesnt work for me or where should I write it  ? I am simply executing that in Command Prompt! And also in the other solution where should I add `<add .... />` ??

Comment: not sure where you're executing commands, do you have a connection string somewhere? Also - the screenshot is not too useful, how about the text of any one of the SQL errors?

Comment: @sq33G :  I ll add the text of the error and I have still not added any connection string yet . It doesnt allow me to add a DB how do I add the connectionString without it ?

Comment: @sq33G : Please see the screen capture I have added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not sure about it but try this delete and recreate your LocalDB\v11.0 database! At the command prompt

```
sqllocaldb delete v11.0
sqllocaldb create v11.0
```

Comment: This is something which I found : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30383/cannot-start-sqllocaldb-instance-with-my-windows-account Is this what you are trying to say ?

Comment: ya i got refrenced from that page hope it may help you

Comment: anytime  abhishek Ghosh

Comment: I have been facing this problem since a month  thanks again ! :)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the `create v11.0` and that hasn't worked. One thing that failed for me in the past but worked for me here is to add the `-s` flag the `create v11.0` to make sure the database starts.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to connect LocalDB to Visual Studio Server Explorer

```
1.Open command prompt
2.Run SqlLocalDB.exe start v11.0 3,Run SqlLocalDB.exe info v11.0
4.Copy the Instance pipe name that starts with np:\...
5.In Visual Studio select TOOLS > Connect to Database...
6.For Server Name enter (localdb)\v11.0. If it didn't work, use the Instance pipe name that you copied earlier. You can also use this to connect with SQL Management Studio.
7.Select the database on next dropdown list
8.Click OK!
```

[This is a demo pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAGSP.png)

you can get help from
 [How to connect to LocalDB in Visual Studio Server Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer)

Comment: I get the following error when I execute the 2nd command : `Start of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error:
Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start`