# LocalDB not recognized in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

I'm trying to create a database-first ASP.NET MVC app with Entity Framework in Visual Studio.

Starting with a blank project template, I open up the Server Explorer and try to add a data connection. I use Microsoft SQL Server as the Data Source, and "(localdb)\v11.0" as the Server Name. This gives me the error:

> "The Data Source value in the connection string specifies an instance
>   of SQL server that is not installed. To resolve the issue, either
>   choose to install the matching instance of SQL Server or modify the
>   Data Source value in the connection string."

The tutorial I'm following (and a few other places I've googled) mentions that localdb is installed with Visual Studio. Either way, I have also installed LocalDB found [here](https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizard.aspx?wizid=932d09f6-e2d4-429d-bd3e-834adabc4f8f&lcid=1033&ci=51) but it's not showing up.

I've tried following the directions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer), but get the error "Cannot create an automatic instance."

How do I get Visual Studio to connect to LocalDB?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The default instance name is changed to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` independent of version numbers for VS 2015.

More info here: http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2015-02-05-VersionindependentlocalDBinVisualStudio2015

Comment: Thank you for this info!