# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Getting this error when I try click onto my "Players Page", Created the seed method and then this happens:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPMW.png

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself is self-explanatory.

It can't find dbo.TeamPlayers.

Check the EF connection string, check that you have permission on this table, etc.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LeagueContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Nfl-20151113064637.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Nfl-20151113064637;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I had it working but then changed, not sure why it's since changed

Comment: Try this to see if you can see your table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer