# Cannot add new Local Database in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

I am going through a tutorial that is adding a simple local database to a C# console application but when adding a new item to the solution I cannot find the Local Database to insert a .sdf database file. I have tried to download SQL Server Compact 4.0 but upon installation it says that SQL Server Compact 4.0 is already installed on the computer. Below is a screenshot of the available data resources I can add.
[image]

How would I be able to add a local database file to my solution?

Comment: SQL Server Compact has been discontinued in VS2013. You could use  `LocalDB` instead.

Comment: @S.Akbari I have LocalDB installed on my pc but still cant add a new "Local Database" to my solution. None of the options allow for a .sdf database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to LocalDB in Visual Studio Server Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ADO.NET Entity Data Model and use Entity Framework to generate models from your database. You can select your local database there.

Comment: Problem is I cannot create a local database in my solution. The ADO.NET EF requires there to be an existing DB

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found this question that has already been answered that solved my problem

[How to connect to LocalDB in Visual Studio Server Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer)