# Local database in visual studio 2015 ASP.NET web application

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

NET web application project.

There is little website of books and I want to save the names of books and authors into the database.

I ask if it's possible to create a local sql server database in the project and to save the books here.

I'm newbie to Web programming.

For example,in Android studio there was SQLite database and SQLiteOpenHelper classes where I was able to create local database in the project.

Is it possible in Visual studio 2015?

Comment: Visual Studio is just a glorified code editor. You're confusing the programming libraries with the code editor. They are different. Did you try doing a basic web search for ".NET SQLite"?

Comment: I need a Microsoft sql server database,not .Net Sqlite.I thought it was good way to create local database.If it's impossible,I've to connect from visual studio to sql server database,have not I?

Comment: Then did you try a web search for "visual studio local database sql server"? Seems like if you did some basic research, you'd end up somewhere helpful like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer).

Comment: Ok.I'll see.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We got a project called local database - SQL Server Compact Database (*.sdf) in visual studio u can make use of it.
(a) In Solution Explorer,right-click on your application then select "Add" -> "New Item".
(b) Go to "Data" -> "Local database" then click on the "Add" button.
(c) Then go to the Server Explorer then expand your database ("MyDB.sdf") then right-click on "Table" then select "Create Table".
(d)And u'll end up in wizard for creating table or for other operations.

This link helps you to set it up.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/curd-operation-in-local-database-sdf-file-in-window-appli/