# EntityFramework 6.0.0.0 reads data, but it is not inserting

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've created a **Service-based Database** `folderName->Add New Item->Data->Service-based Database` file into WPF application. Then I've used `Database First` approach and have created the `PersonsModel.edmx` file. These operations are executed perfectly.

**The reading of data works okay**:

```
using (PersonDBEntities db = new PersonDBEntities())
{
   string dep = (db.Departament.FirstOrDefault()).DepName;//data can be read perfectly
   string bureau = (db.Bureau.FirstOrDefault()).BureauName;//data can be read perfectly 
}
```

**However, data can not be inserted**(this code works in other projects very well) :

```
using (PersonDBEntities db = new PersonDBEntities())
{
   try 
   {
      Departament dep = new Departament() { DepName = "NewDep" };
      db.Departament.Add(dep);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      string message = ex.Message;
   }                
 }
```

Does anybody know why data is not inserted?

No errors, exceptions, just EF is not writing data.

I've [upload a project to github](https://github.com/NiceStepUp/EFWPFMVVMExample), maybe it can be interesting to see:).

A SQL query to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Departament] (
    [IdDep]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DepName] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdDep] ASC)
);
```

and EF model class:

```
public partial class Departament
{
    public Departament()
    {
        this.Person = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int IdDep { get; set; }
    public string DepName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
}
```

What Console of Visual Studio 2013 outputs:

> Started transaction at 18.09.2016 1:34:15 +03:00
>
> INSERT [dbo].Departament VALUES (@0) SELECT [IdDep] FROM
>   [dbo].[Departament] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [IdDep] =
>   scope_identity()
>
> -- @0: '311' (Type = String, Size = 100)
>
> -- Executing at 18.09.2016 1:34:15 +03:00
>
> -- Completed in 79 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Committed transaction at 18.09.2016 1:34:15 +03:00
>
> Closed connection at 18.09.2016 1:34:15 +03:00

*If I run the above query as a SQL database query in Visual Studio 2013, then it inserts data perfectly.*

I've tried the following approaches in sequential order:

```
//db.Departament.Add(dep);//not working
//db.Entry(dep).State = EntityState.Added;//not working
//db.Departament.Attach(dep);//not working
//db.Entry(dep).State = dep.IdDep == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;//not working
//db.Departament.Attach(dep);//not working
db.Entry(dep).State = EntityState.Modified;//not working
```

Comment: Can you send Department table schema ?  Did you set a primary key in the table ? 
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: What is the SQL query EF is generating when you run the `Add`? Check `Immediate Window` in VS.

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag please, see updated section of my question

Comment: If you can get the query from your IDE (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/6830901) and run it against your DB it would be useful.

Comment: @LJ please, see my updated question with what SQL query is run and its result.

Comment: We might need to tell the `EF` that the context is modified. Could you please try with - `EntityState.Modified` on the entity state?

Comment: @LJ nothing added. I've updated my question about what I've tried.

Comment: Can we try `Attach` ; `db.Departament.Attach(dep)` as  we are inserting a new entry; Apologies for keeping you long as it is taking time to understand the underlying logic.

Comment: @LJ it is okay:). But `db.Departament.Attach(dep);` is not inserting data.

Comment: It will attach to the object and on `SaveChanges` it should be reflected on the DB. Is it not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123614/discussion-between-stepup-and-l-j).

Comment: Departament class is partial. What are the other declarations of this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Special thanks to Magnus Montin as he has shown the mistake.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d7362f9-6ea6-4221-a820-c45a41f16688/entityframework-6000-reads-data-but-it-is-not-inserting?forum=wpf) and I just copy his answer:

> But since the INSERT statement is executed and you don't get any
>   exception, how do you confirm that that the data is not inserted? Make
>   sure that you are looking in the right database. That is the database
>   that is located in the output folder of your executable (.exe),
>   typically 'c:\yourprojectfolder\bin\Debug\' or
>   'c:\yourprojectfolder\bin\Release\'. This is where the data gets
>   written by default.

What I've done to avoid this behaviour is I just write absolute path to my database. Now it looks like that:

```
<connectionStrings>   
    <add name="PersonDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.PersonModel.csdl|res://*/Model.PersonModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.PersonModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
      data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=E:\Projects\WPF\EntityFrameworkCRUDDataGridWPF\EntityFrameworkCRUDDataGridWPF\AppData\EmployeeDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Some additional info:

*When you run your application( hit F5 or CTRL+F5 ), Visual Studio copies all of the files including the database MDF file to the bin folder.* **All changes are made to that database which is copied to bin folder.**

Answer (score 1):

Set IdDep column **[Key]** and  **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]** attributes

```
public partial class Departament
{
    public Departament()
    {
        this.Person = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdDep { get; set; }
    public string DepName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried to do this, but it does not help. No new data is added to `Department` table.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine; only thing which I think to be looked up for are:

- The connection string (Make sure that the entity being updated are in the correct database; since you are using LocalDB, ping against that particular database table using `Server Explorer`
- Please also take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343750/6830901 and update your connection string based on the SQL Server you are targeting at.
- The code below should work if no EF exceptions are thrown (based on points above)

  ```
      using (PersonDBEntities db = new PersonDBEntities())
      {
          try
          {
              Departament dep = new Departament() { DepName = "New Department" };
              db.Departament.Add(dep);
              db.SaveChanges();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          }
      }
  ```