# Values not inserted in table

Tags: entity-framework

I have company table where values are inserted

```
public int SaveCompany(Company objCompany)
{

  int CompanyID = 0

  try
  {
    using (var context = new Cubicle_EntityEntities())
    {
      context.Companies.Add(objCompany);        //add entity to the add method
      int res = context.SaveChanges();       //insert it into table
      if (res > 0)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("Data Inserted Successfully");
      }
      else
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("Try Again");
      }
      CompanyID = objCompany.CompanyId;
      Debug.WriteLine("CompanyId " + CompanyID);

    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

     CompanyID = 0;
     bool rethrow = UserInterfaceExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref ex);
     throw ex;
   }       

   return CompanyID;
 }
```

Every time I get res 1,but data not inserted in table.

Comment: Do you get any value in CompanyID = objCompany.CompanyId;?

Comment: yes I get incremented value for company id everytime

Comment: And selecting from database works fine?

Comment: yes it works fine

Comment: This should work fine. Take a look at this, maybe that helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552207/entityframework-6-0-0-0-reads-data-but-it-is-not-inserting