# Where does ASP.NET core put automatically created Databases?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am following an MVC tutorial on ASP.NET core and currently  created a movie database application using scaffolding.

The application can create and display movies entries but I can't locate the database in my MSSMS.is it hidden? I have looked into the system database table with no luck.
I know the  database exists because the application  can persist the data.
Tutorial Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Search localdb. You can access it in VS. You can connect to it using SSMS

Comment: Have you trying refreshing? the GUI could be not showing because you didn't refresh the visualization. If you refresh and couldn't see, try restarting it

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saved to a SQL Server Express LocalDB instance, using the [connectionstring in appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-generated-database-connection-string).

You can connect to it with SSMS using this server name: `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`

Comment: Thank you the server name was (localdb)\mssqllocaldb, i had to remove the extra back slash

Comment: Could you edit your answer as I don't have edit privileges.

Comment: Removed the extra backslash. I mistakenly copied it verbatim from the connectionstring, where an extra backslash is required as C# uses it as the beginning of an escape sequence.